# Keep headers in groupby filtering even if dataFrame is empty

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I want to keep columns-header when I use groupby filtering even if dataframe is empty.

I filter dataframe as following

```
df_groupby = df.groupby("ID",as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[x["col"] == x["col"].max()]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_groupby)

   ID  col
0   1    4
1   2    5
```

This works if dataframe is not empty. Howerver, if record is empty this filtering drops columns-header

```
df_empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "col"])
df_groupby = df_empty.groupby("ID",as_index=False,group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x[x["col"] == x["col"].max()]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_groupby)

-
```

I expect no-record dataframe with headers as

```
   ID  col
```

My temporary solution is to add this lines after filtering.

```
if df_groupby.empty:
   df_groupby = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_empty.columns)
```

I certainly think there should have a better way to filter.
How can I cover empty dataframe when I filter ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` for new `Series` filled by max values of group, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and also return column names for empty `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "col"])

df_groupby = df[df.groupby("ID")["col"].transform('max') == df['col']].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_groupby)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, col]
Index: []
```

Test with data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'ID':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'col':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
})


df_groupby = df[df.groupby("ID")["col"].transform('max') == df['col']].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_groupby)
   ID  col
0   5    8
1   4    9
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df.groupby("ID")["col"].transform('max'))
0    9
1    8
2    9
3    8
4    8
5    9
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) - but it return always only one row per group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "col"])

df_groupby = df.sort_values(['ID','col'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates('ID')
print(df_groupby)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, col]
Index: []
```